Delete from same table using inner join seems to be failing (both records removed)
I have a table which has both ChildID and ParentID. Due to the way the data was compiled, in some cases those values are reversed. So I wrote what I thought was a simple Inner Join where both values are reversed and tried to delete the first tables value. I seem to remember this working fine before except now this del
Delete S1 from TableA S1
Inner Join TableA S2 
On S1.ChildID=S2.ParentID
and S1.ParentID=S2.ChildID

https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=bc5a98e7-efd9-443c-87d9-3eba3304da82

" tried to delete the first tables value". What first table? The join is between the same table. I assume you mean "records", but what is the criteria? The SQL shows you want to delete records where the criss-cross ids exist and that is what happens in your sqlfiddle, which is the correct behavior. Can you please offer more details what you want to delete exactly from your sqlfiddle example? To me, it's not clear. Your test seems to be correct so there must be some other information missing from the question.

it depends which column you will keep.
from that data it is imppssible to tell.
but i comews to you need to differentiate which between the IDs, that determines which column will be deleted
-- INIT database
CREATE TABLE TableA (
  ID  INT,
  ChildID INT,
  ParentID INT
);



INSERT INTO TableA (ID,ChildID,ParentID) VALUES (1,89,891);
INSERT INTO TableA (ID,ChildID,ParentID) VALUES (2,99,991);
INSERT INTO TableA (ID,ChildID,ParentID) VALUES (3,991,99);
-- QUERY database



Delete S1 from TableA S1
    Inner Join TableA S2 
    On S1.ChildID=S2.ParentID
    and S1.ParentID=S2.ChildID
    AND S1.ID < S2.ID;
Select * from TableA;




ID
ChildID
ParentID




1
89
891


3
991
99



INSERT INTO TableA (ID,ChildID,ParentID) VALUES (2,99,991);

Delete S1 from TableA S1
    Inner Join TableA S2 
    On S1.ChildID=S2.ParentID
    and S1.ParentID=S2.ChildID
    AND S1.ID > S2.ID;
Select * from TableA;




ID
ChildID
ParentID




1
89
891


2
99
991



fiddle

of course, thank you. It is identical to removing dupes from the same table, I forgot I had to specify by some other criteria. Thank you.
